# Implementing reportviewer find function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

On my page, I have reportviewer.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    CssClass="ReportViewer" AsyncRendering="false" 
    OnPreRender="RptViewer_PreRender" EnableViewState="true" 
    Width="100%" PageCountMode="Actual"
    WaitMessageFont-Size="1.2em" ShowToolBar="true" 
    Visible="true"
    InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)">  
    <LocalReport></LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I'm trying to integrate it with my toolbar that will also have functionalities provided by reportviewer toolbar. So I'm not using reportviewer's toolbar.

On my toolbar I have image and textbox:

```
<img src="img/search.png" alt="Find" onClick="findString()" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here's my script:

```
function findString() {
    var viewer = $("#ReportViewer1");
    var searchText = document.getElementByID('<%=txtSearch.ClientID>');
    if (!viewer.get_isLoading() && viewer.get_reportAreaContentType() == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) {
        viewer.find(str);
    }
    return false;
}

function nextHit() {
    var viewer = $("#ReportViewer1");
    if (!viewer.get_isLoading() && viewer.get_reportAreaContentType() == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) {
        viewer.findNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

In function `findString`, I'm getting (I saw in firebug) `isLoading` is a property & not a function. Am I missing something?

If I change my function as:

```
function findString() {
    var viewer = $("#ReportViewer1");
    var searchText = document.getElementByID('<%=txtSearch.ClientID>');

        viewer.find(str);

    return false;
}
```

I don't see that error, but don't see the search text highlighted in the report. Help.

Comment: do you try viewer.get_isLoading ? without "()" like a prop.

Comment: No. But I got this idea from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'll check ... I see using $find, which is not a standard ... maybe that is related. Here explains how it works $find http://web.archive.org/web/20100212204840/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html